# How to save uploaded files to models and serve them in templates?

Tags: django, django-2.0

I've been following the django 2 official tutorial but I'm a bit confused as how to work with images and uploaded files.

I have a project with a few apps. Let's call the project myProj and the app myApp. There is a model in myApp called myModel which has an image field myImage.
**Here is my model:**

```
from django.db import models

class myModel(models.Model):
    myImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='myApp_images')
```

**Here is my template:**

```
<img src="{{ n.image }}"></img>
```

**Here is my view**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import myModel

def index(request):
    n = myModel.objects[0]
    context = {
        'n': n,
        }
    return render(request, 'myModel/index.html', context)
```

**And here is my settings:(parts I thought were relevant)**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'news.apps.myModelConfig',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/aran/myfiles/projects/futureCoin/media/'
```

**Here is my myProject/urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import  admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('myModel/', include('myModel.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

So I made an instance of the model through the django admin site.
**Here is the directory tree after that(I removed the pycache):**

```
.
├── myProject
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── manage.py
├── media
│   └── myModel_images
│       └── myImage.jpeg
├── myModel
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── myModel
│   │       ├── images
│   │       │   └── bg.jpg
│   │       └── style.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── myModel
│   │       └── index.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
```

Now the problem is that when I try to open the index page the image is not shown because the url to it is: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/myModel/myModel_images/myImage.jpg`
however if I manualy open the url:`http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/myModel_images/myImage.jpg` I see the right Image. Can anyone please help me understand where the problem is and how I can fix it? Any other feedback on my code would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What happens when I do `n.image` and why does it give me a url but a wrong url?**

It's not a wrong url at all. That's because `n.image` returns the url path of the image like `/path/to/image.jpg` exactly the way that you have set up in your ImageField `upload_to`

```
myImage = models.ImageField(upload_to='myApp_images')
```

by default this will be prefixed by your url address and becomes `127.0.0.1:8000/path/to/image.jpg`. As you can see it misses the `/media/` as provided in `settings.MEDIA_URL` where your all images are localized.

So now by using `{{ n.image.url}}`, you actually call it from your settings configuration, your `MEDIA_URL` `/media/` will be added  as prefix and becomes `/media/path/to/image.jpg` prefixed by the url `127.0.0.1:8000`

To fix it, in your template, access the image url with `{{instance.field.url}}`

try:

```
<img src="{{ n.image.url }}"></img>
```

instead of

```
<img src="{{ n.image }}"></img>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. But would you be so kind to explain to me what happens when I do n.image and why does it give me a url but a wrong url?

Comment: Updated my answer, and explained what was wrong  and why